# Does Gazebo simulate air resistance?

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Does gazebo realistically simulate the air resistance? I see you can set an atmospheric pressure in the simulation but I don't know how to validate the correctness of the aerodynamics. I need the simulation to generate a realistic forces acting on the link given the geometry and velocity of the link. Does gazebo do that or do I need to make a plugin for this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23526/does-gazebo-simulate-air-resistance?/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2019-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi.

I created based on the hectorplugins a simple plugin that generated drag to a model, in whatever direction. It's a basic approach but at least it should get you going in the right direction.

[image: image description]

Here you have the whole code for the solution:

[Video explaining the solution and demo](https://youtu.be/8VzyWskliUI)

[ROSJect Plug and play project with solution](http://www.rosject.io/l/bfbe61b/)

[Git with all the solution](https://bitbucket.org/theconstructcore/buoyancy_tests_pkg/src)

I'll post here the file for the plugin creation:
[C:\fakepath\fluid_resitance.cpp](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/15665616689550999.cpp)

And a snippet on how to use it in a Model URDF:

```
<!-- Add plugin Air Resistance -->
<gazebo>
    <plugin name="fluid_resitance_plugin" filename="libfluid_resitance_plugin.so">
        <fluid_resitanceTopicName>/fluid_resitance</fluid_resitanceTopicName>
        <NameLinkToApplyResitance>simple_sphere_base_link</NameLinkToApplyResitance>
        <rate>2.0</rate>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

Hope it helps ;).

---

Originally posted by [Duckfrost](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2616/duckfrost/) with karma: 209 on 2019-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1